# using break and continue in for loop to iterate through dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm a beginner and need some help. I need to use a for loop with break and continue to find the first person that has a dog in a list. The iteration count should not exceed 2.

Here is the given list:

```
people = [
    {'name': "Daniel", 'age': 29, 'job': "Engineer", 'pet': "Cat", 'pet_name': "Gato"}, 
    {'name': "Katie", 'age': 30, 'job': "Teacher", 'pet': "Dog", 'pet_name': "Frank"},
    {'name': "Owen", 'age': 26, 'job': "Sales person", 'pet': "Cat", 'pet_name': "Cosmo"},
    {'name': "Josh", 'age': 22, 'job': "Student", 'pet': "Cat", 'pet_name': "Chat"},
    {'name': "Estelle", 'age': 35, 'job': "French Diplomat", 'pet': "Dog", 'pet_name': "Gabby"},
    {'name': "Gustav", 'age': 24, 'job': "Brewer", 'pet': "Dog", 'pet_name': "Helen"}
]
```

and the following code was given to start:

```
first_dog_person = None
iteration_count = 0
for value in people:
    iteration_count += 1
```

My thought process is using an if statement to iterate through the first two keys and find the value that equals "Dog". But I can't visualize it in my head to enter the code.

I've also learned how to create an empty list for ex. first_dog_person = [] and append key, value pairs to the new list but I can't figure out how to make the element equal the key (first_dog_person = None).

Comment: You're making it harder than it needs to be.  Your loop is giving you the entries one by one.  `if value['pet'] == 'Dog':` is all you need.

Comment: Thank you! I was overthinking it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using if statement, like in example below:

```
first_dog_person = None
iteration_count = 0
for value in people:
    iteration_count += 1
    
    # To ensure that iteration won't exceed 2
    if iteration_count == 2:
       break
    
    if value['pet'] == 'Dog':
        first_dog_person = value
```

If you want to check key value for a current dictionary item, simply just pass it in square brackets like

> value['pet']

in example above.

After making sure that your item value meets the requirements, you can simply assign it to the created variable "first_dog_person".

Be sure to check out Python Docs and read about some Data Structures — [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=dictionary#dictionaries)

Comment: your loop won't find the person with a dog (because it will break on the second iteration before checking if the person has a dog (it should be `if iteration_count > 2:`)), also comments in python are marked with a `#`

Comment: It would be better to break in the "pet == Dog" clause, and then print the iteration_count as a verification.

Comment: You're most certainly right. Thanks for editing comment and break condition!